# Get Knowledge Articles using Salesforce REST API

Tags: rest-api, integration, knowledge, articles

I'm working on an integration of Salesforce Knowledge Base
consuming the Salesforce REST API (following this [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_resources.htm)).

I'd like to consume the Knowledge Articles that are loaded in my Salesforce
domain. So I've some *questions* for you if you can help me with this.

1. Is the endpoint */services/data/vXX.X/support/knowledgeArticles* the
   correct way to consume the loaded information of the knowledge base?
2. If so, I noticed that there is no *body* property, is this property
   replaced by the *summary* property? If not, how can I have all the
   information of all the loaded articles (e.g. title + body + categories)
3. Does Salesforce have any *playground* which I can consume instead of
   having the domain of Salesforce (for testing purpose)

I really appreciate if you have more information about this, as I
didn't find any example

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: With regards to point 3 you can sign up to free dev orgs or start a trailhead account. Trailhead is probably the way to go as you can take a look at the Knowledge and REST API specific content on there as well.

Comment: Also this link may help more: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_rest_manage.htm

Comment: Oh that's great, thankss @Girbot!